# SQLAlchemy implement ARRAY-like column (no postgresql)

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I am aware that similar things were asked before, but I could not find an answer that was fitting my purposes. If there is one, I apologize deeply, and please do mark my question as duplicate!

I am dealing with databases containing numerical values, using SQLAlchemy. Some of them are Cartesian 3D coordinates in the form (x, y, z). As an example, let's say that I have an "Asset" class that represents renderable objects with a position and a texture (the latter being a string to a file, it's just for sake of the example). This is what I would write right now:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sql

class Asset(Base):
    """A renderable object in 3D."""
    __tablename__ = "assets"

    # A unique id for this asset.
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # File with the 3D object.
    mesh = sql.Column(sql.String(80), nullable=False)
    
    # 3D position of the object.
    position_x = sql.Column(sql.Float, nullable=False)
    position_y = sql.Column(sql.Float, nullable=False)
    position_z = sql.Column(sql.Float, nullable=False)

    @property
    def position(self):
        return self.position_x, self.position_y, self.position_z
```

The `position` property is just for ease of use later in my code - I use the coordinates as a single 3D vector, and this at least removes the need to create such a structure manually each time.

When I try to add new objects to the database, I want to avoid duplicates if possible. This means that whenever I try to add an object to the database, I check if an entry with the same attributes exists already. If so, I do not add the object. This translates in the following code:

```py
def add_asset(mesh: str, position: Tuple[float, float, float]) -> bool:
    engine = sql.create_engine("DB_URL")
    with sql.orm.Session(engine) as session:
        # Check if an asset with the same properties already exists.
        x, y, z = position
        asset = session.query(Asset).filter(
            sql.func.abs(x - Asset.position_x) < 1e-6,
            sql.func.abs(y - Asset.position_x) < 1e-6,
            sql.func.abs(z - Asset.position_x) < 1e-6
        ).filter_by(mesh=mesh).first()

        # Match found? Exit and return "not added"!
        if asset is not None:
            return False

        # Match not found: add the asset and return "added".
        session.add(Asset(mesh=mesh, position_x=x, position_y=y, position_z=z))
        session.commit()
        return True
```

The `sql.func.abs(x - Asset.position_x) < 1e-6` is to handle the fact that `Float` values should not be filtered using equality. The "tolerance" here is rather large, but this is actually on purpose since I do not need sub-micrometric precision!

Note that the code used to process `position_x`, `position_y` and `position_z` is essentially the same. In addition, I actually need to store N-dimensinal vectors in many other places, with N being known in advance (not at runtime only) but for different values of N depending on the context (what I mean is that I have 2D vectors in some places, 3D and even 6D vectors in others, etc.).

What I would like to do is to create a new type of column (let's call it `Vector`) that allows to avoid writing N times the same lines of code. Ideally I would like to transform the code above into something like:

```py
class Asset(Base):
    """A renderable object in 3D."""
    __tablename__ = "assets"

    # A unique id for this asset.
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # File with the 3D object.
    mesh = sql.Column(sql.String(80), nullable=False)
    
    # 3D position of the object.
    position = sql.Column(Vector(3), nullable=False)


def add_asset(mesh: str, position: Tuple[float, float, float]) -> bool:
    engine = sql.create_engine("DB_URL")
    with sql.orm.Session(engine) as session:
        # Check if an asset with the same properties already exists.
        asset = session.query(Asset).filter(
            close(position, Asset.position, 1e-6)
        ).filter_by(mesh=mesh).first()

        # Match found? Exit and return "not added"!
        if asset is not None:
            return False

        # Match not found: add the asset and return "added".
        session.add(Asset(mesh=mesh, position=position))
        session.commit()
        return True
```

I know there is an `ARRAY` column type in PostgreSQL, but I cannot use that - I mean, PostgreQLS.

The closest I got so far is the following:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sql
from sqlalchemy.ext import hybrid

class Asset(Base):
    """A renderable object in 3D."""
    __tablename__ = "assets"

    # A unique id for this asset.
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # File with the 3D object.
    mesh = sql.Column(sql.String(80), nullable=False)
    
    # 3D position of the object.
    px, py, pz = (sql.Column(sql.Float, nullable=False) for _ in range(3))

    @hybrid_property
    def position(self):
        return self.px, self.py, self.pz


def close_to(properties, values, tolerance):
   return sql.all_(*(sql.func.abs(p - v) < tolerance for p, v in zip(properties, values)))


def add_asset(mesh: str, position: Tuple[float, float, float]) -> bool:
    engine = sql.create_engine("DB_URL")
    with sql.orm.Session(engine) as session:
        # Check if an asset with the same properties already exists.
        asset = session.query(Asset).filter(
            close_to(Asset.position, position, 1e-6)
        ).filter_by(mesh=mesh).first()

        # Match found? Exit and return "not added"!
        if asset is not None:
            return False

        # Match not found: add the asset and return "added".
        session.add(Asset(mesh=mesh, px=position[0], py=position[1], pz=position[2]))
        session.commit()
        return True
```

But I still don't like that for each vector I need to:

- Declare fields separately: `px, py, pz = (sql.Column(...) for _ in range(3))`
- Add a `hybrid_property`, manually.
- Initialize the attributes one by one in the constructor: `px=position[0], py=position[1], pz=position[2]`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with a "crafty" solution. I am not sure if this is the way to go, but it looks like it is getting the job done... So here it is!

The idea is as follows:

- Create a dummy column class named `VectorColumnPlaceHolder` that simply stores an integer - the dimension of the vector. It also has a static method named `process` that I will detail later.
- Define the database class as usual. For vector elements, use something like `position = VectorColumnPlaceHolder(3)`.
- We then call the method `VectorColumnPlaceHolder.process()` on the class that contains vector columns. This is where the "real magic" happens. What this method does is:

  - Scan all attributes of the class, looking for `VectorColumnPlaceHolder` instances.
  - For each of them, add a set of columns named `<column_name>_i`, with `i` being an index that ranges from `0` to `N-1`. As an example, if we specified the column `position = VectorColumnPlaceHolder(3)`, this would be processed by adding the columns `position_0`, `position_1` and `position_2`.
  - In addition, one hybrid property is added (with getter and setter) that allows to retrieve/modify all coordinates at once. Being a hybrid property, it can be used to build queries as well! This new property replaces the original `VectorColumnPlaceHolder` instance.

My example above (`Asset`) would become:

```py
class Asset(Base):
    """A renderable object in 3D."""
    __tablename__ = "assets"

    # A unique id for this asset.
    id = sql.Column(sql.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # File with the 3D object.
    mesh = sql.Column(sql.String(80), nullable=False)
    
    # 3D position of the object.
    position = VectorColumnPlaceHolder(3)

# Replace VectorColumnPlaceHolder with columns and properties.
# After this call:
# - The columns Asset.position_0,  Asset.position_1 and  Asset.position_2 are added.
# - Asset.position (initially a VectorColumnPlaceHolder) is replaced with a hybrid property.
VectorColumnPlaceHolder.process(Asset)


def close_to(properties, values, tolerance):
   return sql.all_(*(sql.func.abs(p - v) < tolerance
                     for p, v in zip(properties, values)))


def add_asset(mesh: str, position: Tuple[float, float, float]) -> bool:
    engine = sql.create_engine("DB_URL")
    with sql.orm.Session(engine) as session:
        # Check if an asset with the same properties already exists.
        asset = session.query(Asset).filter(
            close_to(Asset.position, position, 1e-6)
        ).filter_by(mesh=mesh).first()

        # Match found? Exit and return "not added"!
        if asset is not None:
            return False

        # Match not found: add the asset and return "added".
        session.add(Asset(mesh=mesh, position=position))
        session.commit()
        return True
```

And here is the class `VectorColumnPlaceHolder`:

```py
class VectorColumnPlaceHolder(object):
    """A "dummy" SQL column, representing an N-dimensional vector."""

    def __init__(self, n: int, column_factory=None):
        """Create a vector placeholder.

        Args:
            n: Dimension of the vector.
            column_factory: Callable that can create a new column. Vector coordinates are created as individual columns,
                and each of them is created by calling this function. The parameter is optional, and by default columns
                are created as sql.Column(sql.Float, nullable=False).
        """
        if n < 1:
            raise ValueError(f"Number of coordinates must be a positive integer, not '{n}'.")
        self.n = n
        if column_factory is None:
            self.create_coordinate = lambda: sql.Column(sql.Float, nullable=False)
        else:
            self.create_coordinate = column_factory

    @staticmethod
    def process(Class):
        """Dynamically add columns in place of VectorColumnPlaceHolder objects inside the given class.

        Args:
            Class: Class for which the VectorColumnPlaceHolder should be replaced by as set of columns and hybrid
                properties.
        """
        # Inspect all attributes of the class and process those that represent "vector columns".
        for column_name in dir(Class):
            column = getattr(Class, column_name)
            if isinstance(column, VectorColumnPlaceHolder):
                # Add one column per vector coordinate.
                for i in range(column.n):
                    setattr(Class, f"{column_name}_{i}", column.create_coordinate())

                # Add a hybrid property representing the set of coordinates as a whole. It can be used to access the
                # values as Class.column_name - both to retrieve the values and to use the fields in queries.
                @hybrid_property
                def vector_hybrid(self, column_name=column_name, n=column.n):
                    return tuple(getattr(self, f"{column_name}_{i}") for i in range(n))

                # Add a setter to give a value to each coordinate at once.
                @vector_hybrid.setter
                def vector_hybrid(self, value, column_name=column_name, n=column.n):
                    for i in range(n):
                        setattr(self, f"{column_name}_{i}", value[i])

                # Add the hybrid property to the class - this replaces the VectorColumnPlaceHolder.
                setattr(Class, column_name, vector_hybrid)
```